# VirtualBox Guest VPN inside Host VPN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn, network-adapter

On my host, I have NordVPN up and running and I shared the internet connection of the VPN adapter on the IP adress 192.168.137.1. I created a new VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet network adapter and set it's IP adress to 192.168.137.1 and network mask to 255.255.255.0 (and disabled the dhcp server). I set the network adapter of the VM to said host-only adapter. After booting up the guest, I changed the settings of the Ethernet adapter inside my guest to:

- IPv4 Adress: 192.168.137.x (some number for x)
- Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.137.1
- some DNS server so it won't cause DNS leakage

Now inside my VM, I set up the VPN Windscribe. Without it connected to a server, if I tracert to google, I can see the route going through my host VPN IP adress. However, if I connect to a server with Windscribe, tracert doesn't show the IP adress of the host VPN even though all internet traffic from the VM should be channeled through the host VPN adapter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's normal. tracert should only show you what happens within the tunnel, so you would see traffics go directly to the Windscribe gateway.

Comment: If you see it goes to the host and then the "outer" VPN frist, it isn't even tunneled then.

Comment: Oh thanks, O didn't know! I don't see it going to the outer VPN, just the host (or the IP Address that the interface connected to the host-only adapter has) and then an IP address that looks similar to the one I get from the VPN server (last three digits are different). Could you recommend any other way for testing if my setup works meaning I can achieve a tunnel within a tunnel?

Comment: The way I could think of is checking traffics of the outer tunnel (with tcpdump or so), see if there are any going to/from the inner VPN server's public address.

Comment: Since my hosts os is windows, I just tried it with Wireshark instead. I'm no expert at this but when I'm starting a ping -t at google in my guest without the guest VPN connected, I can see the echo ping requests and replies. If I connect Windscribe in my guest and start the ping again, I can't see any pings in Wireshark, all I see is mostly "application data". I might be a dummdumm, but I guess this would mean that the actual traffic from the guest isn't visible anymore to the host in it's unencrypted form, meaning that I do have achieved a tunnel within an tunnel